# How do I print a PetscBag to a specific file?

Tags: petsc

I have a PetscBag in my program that I want to write to a filename I have stored as a string. If I want to write to `stdout`, there is a pre-made PetscViewer macro for that. How do I create a viewer for a PetscBag that writes to a specified file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewers are discussed in the [PETSc user guide](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf).  Create one using [`PetscViewerASCIIOpen`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerASCIIOpen.html) or [`PetscViewerBinaryOpen`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Viewer/PetscViewerBinaryOpen.html), then call [`PetscBagView`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/PetscBagView.html) on your viewer.